# Azure Function - Pandas dataframe to Excel, write to outputBlob stream

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Am trying to write a DataFrame to an outputBlob from an Azure Function. I'm having trouble figuring out which io stream to use.

My function looks like this:

```
    import io
    import xlrd
    import pandas as pd

    def main(myblob: func.InputStream, outputBlob: func.Out[func.InputStream]):
        logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                     f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                     f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
        input_file = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = myblob.read())
        df = pd.read_excel(input_file)
        if not df.empty:
            output = io.BytesIO()
            outputBlob.set(runway1.to_excel(output))
```

How do we save the DataFrame to a stream that is recognisable by the Azure Function to write the excel to a Storage Container?

Comment: Could you please tell me your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save DataFrame as excel to Azure blob storage, please refer to the following example

1. SDK

```
azure-functions==1.3.0
numpy==1.19.0
pandas==1.0.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter==1.2.9
```

2. Code

```
import logging
import io
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter 
import azure.functions as func


async def main(myblob: func.InputStream,outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream]):
    
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n")
    input_file = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = myblob.read())
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file)
    if not df.empty:
            xlb=io.BytesIO()
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlb, engine= 'xlsxwriter')
            df.to_excel(writer,index=False)
            writer.save()
            xlb.seek(0) 
            outputblob.set(xlb)
            logging.info("OK")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim. My mistake was not saving the dataframe to an excel writer which would then save into the bytestream.

Comment: What is the point using `func.Out[func.InputStream]` rather than `func.Out[bytes]`?