# Azure Function - Pandas Dataframe to Excel is Empty

Tags: python, excel, pandas, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Having followed the answer from a previous stack overflow question [Azure Function - Pandas Dataframe to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772719/azure-function-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-write-to-outputblob-stream), I've been able to store an xlsx file in a storage blob but the file is empty. I'm debugging locally using Azurite so I can see that the dataframe is not empty and the `outputblob` object is not empty, but the resulting .xlsx file in the storage container is a 0 Byte file.

Here is the relevant "write to blob" code I am running.

```
# Write data to storage blob
        df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=COLUMN_NAMES)
        if not df.empty:
            xlb = io.BytesIO()
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlb, engine= 'xlsxwriter') # pylint: disable=abstract-class-instantiated
            df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
            xlb.seek(0)
            outputblob.set(xlb)
            logging.info(f"Write OK. Number of rows: {df.shape[0]} ")
```

And here is the bindings section from the `function.json`:

```
"bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 2 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputblob",
      "path": "performance-alerting-data/SignInApp/outputblob.xlsx",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I forgot to add `writer.save()` after `df.to_excel()`. It is working correctly now, the Excel file is written to a storage container and is saved as an excel file